# GridLayout images go off screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, grid-layout, android-gridlayout

In the design and blueprint view it looks that it fits, but on app some images go off screen. I want to have all images shown, without scrolling. It doesn't need to support landscape orientation, only portrait. If I move all images up (less bottom-margin on button) then it looks alright in the app as well, but if it fits in the design view it should also on app.

[Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/66Zxk.png)

[App View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUHGB.png)

The code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/GridLayout1"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:columnCount="2"
android:rowCount="8"
android:orientation="horizontal"
tools:context=".MainActivity2" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_button1"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_columnSpan="2"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"
    android:text="Button" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_img1"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_img2"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"/>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_img3"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_img4"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_img5"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_img6"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_img7"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"/>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/my_img8"
    android:layout_gravity="left|top"
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/img1"/>
</GridLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your layout you have **android:layout_marginBottom="160dp"** for the **Button
android:id="@+id/my_button1"** Remove it and it should work.